# JQuery's width() doesn't exclude padding for elements within hidden span

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

I'm trying to get the width of a number of select elements that are hidden. Using width() on the JQuery objects returns a width that is the CSS-defined width but includes padding. Once I toggle the elements to show though, calling width() returns the correct value (i.e. width that excludes padding/border/margins).

sample HTML:

```
<span id="test" style="visibility:hidden">
    <select id="one">
        <option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
   select {
        width: 80px;
        padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    }
```

Expected width: 65, reported width: 80

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2RH7C/4/

Is there a workaround besides setting "visibility: hidden" (instead of display: none), or cloning/moving the objects off screen? I'm using KnockoutJS data bindings to control visibility, and that binding sets display: none (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html).

Comment: It looks like when an element is hidden, the browser takes the width that is set in the style, i.e. 80px. Whereas when rendered/visible, the width is being calculated based on the css width plus padding. Firebug confirms this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in jQuery 1.7 that does not occur in jQuery 1.8:

http://jsfiddle.net/2RH7C/5/

If you don't have the option to update jQuery, then I'm afraid it seems like the "calculate with offscreen element" or `visibility: hidden` methods are your only options.

Comment: Aha! Thank you - unfortunately I don't have that option but that's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

It is the border that is 1px on each side.
With border:none; the result is 65.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that. However, is it possible to get that width of 65 even when the span is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

The javascript is correct. Using width() already eliminates padding. The rendered width will actually be 110px (80+15+15).